# Optimizing Space complexity for a DP solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

**Problem** :

> I have a photo(black and white) given in form of 10 pixels(1-D array
>   of characters 'b' and 'w', b means black and w means white).
>   I
>   also have N filters. Each filter is a 1-D array(size 10) consisting of
>   '+' and ' - ' . You can pick any subset of these N filters and apply
>   them on the photo .
>   Applying a filter : if the **i**<sup>th</sup>
>   character of the filter is '+' invert the **i**<sup>th</sup> pixel in
>   the photo else nothing happens.
>  We need to output the *number of
>   different subsets of filters* we can choose to convert the photo into
>   all black .

**Constraints** :

> 1<=T(number of test cases)<=5
>  1<=N(Number of
>   filters)<=10<sup>5</sup>

**My Approach** :

> The basic idea is that I have a function NumberPossible(i,
>   startingPosition), where i is the index of the filters not used yet.
>   
>  i varies from 0 to n. 
>  Base Case : NumberPossible(n,
>   startingPosition) equals 1 if and only if startingPosition is *all
>   black*.  Otherwise, 0. 
>  Recurrence : NumberPossible(i,
>   startingPosition) = NumberPossible(i+1, applyFilter(i,
>   startingPosition)) + NumberPossible(i+1, startingPosition) That
>   represents how you either apply the filter or you don't apply the
>   filter.

**Question** :

> The following approach times out (probably due to the *expensive* step
>   mentioned in the code). Is there a better algorithm , one where I
>   don't need to store **all** the states and would require less space
>   complexity ?

Comment: See every other time this same problem has been asked in some form.  They get other things wrong but generally recognize you only need two rows of `dp` at a time, current and previous, so you can use `dp[i&1][y]` and `dp[(i+1)&1][y]`  So the time complexity is the same (but faster due to cache) and space is cut to pretty trivial.  You also need to compute in the sequence of required data, rather than recursively.

Comment: But, since there are only 1024 possible filters and original sequence is irrelevant, you can do far better by counting how many of each are available and using them by batch of identical, rather than individually.

Comment: @JSF It gives wrong outputs if i change `dp[i][y] to dp[i&1][y]` and `dp[(i+1)][y] to dp[(i+1)&1][y]`.

Comment: The recursive sequence of computation does not let you use that major space optimization.  You need to switch to a forward computation sequence, computing all values on the other dimension (rather than on demand) because it is too hard to predict which you will need.  It might seem the savings from on-demand are too important to give up.  But the cost of detecting whether a computation was done before, actually adds up to more than the total benefits of on-demand.

Comment: @JSF I don't get what you're saying at all :/ bit of a pseudocode might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of DP is that you recursively work backward from the information you ultimately need through all the intermediate information you need along the way, all the way back to something you can directly compute.  Meanwhile you avoid recomputing any intermediate values that are needed in multiple paths through the recursion.

But the typical reality of DP is that the cost of knowing which intermediate values were already computed makes it cheaper to actually work in the opposite direction.  Start with what you can compute directly.  Compute all of those things whether you know you will need them or not.  Then step to things that can be computed from those and compute all of those, again without knowing whether you need them or not.  In typical situations the excess computations from "whether you end up needing it or not" are trivial compared to the benefits of computing things in an efficient sequence.

There is the semantic question (both sides of which I have seen aggressively maintained) whether that second approach really is DP, or whether DP was only the first approach and the hypothetical DP solution was used to help define a non DP solution.

The **direction** in your problem is a confusing factor in this discussion because either method allows reversible direction, yet the key difference between the two methods is the reverse of direction.  What is really happening is a reverse of direction **relative** to the meanings of the stored answers.

So lets us assume we have already computed `j` as either zero or one and `dp[j][Y]` **for all Y** to represent the combinations taking into account all input **before** `i` for some `i` and some relationship between `i` and `j` (all this happening inside a loop over `i`).

Next we can loop over Y to compute `dp[1-j][Y]` for all Y representing the combinations taking into account all input before and including input `i`.

After that, we either swap `j` with `1-j` (by simply coding `j=1-j;`) or recompute `j` from the next value of `i`.

There are reasons we might want to detect and skip some null positions in the input, which become reasons swapping `j` with `1-j` might be better as an independent operation from incrementing `i`.  But that is a rather advanced optimization.

Since you know how to compute `dp[i+1][y]` from `dp[i][]`, `y` and input `i`, you know how to put all that into a loop over `i` and inner loop over `y` but use `dp[j][]` and `dp[1-j][]` instead.

Next, the bigger optimization is counting input.  Since input sequence is irrelevant, instead of storing `filters[i]=x` we can skip `filters` entirely and use `filter_count[x]++`

Then the main `i` loop is over the 1024 elements of `filter_count` instead of N elements of `filter`.

```
sometype global_multiplier=1;
for (unsigned i=0; i<1024; ++i)
if (filter_count[i]) {  // only do the work if we have any
    // Multiply by half the number of subsets of this filter
    for (unsigned c=filter_count[i]; --c;)
        global_multiplier=(global_multiplier*2)%MOD;

    for (unsigned y=0; y<1024; ++y)
        dp[1-j][y] = (dp[j][y] + dp[j][y^i]) % MOD;
    j=1-j;
    }
```

At the end select the correct position of `dp[j][]` and multiply it by the separately kept `global_multiplier`

You need twice as many digits in the temporary for that single final multiply as there are digits in MOD.  But everywhere else you need just one more bit in values than there are bits in MOD.  If really forced, that last multiply could be done with shift and add so it also needs only one more bit than MOD itself needs.

Comment: I don't think we can do `unsigned c=1<<(filter_count[i]-1);` filter_count can be upto 10^5 here .

Comment: @SarvagyaAgarwal  Good point.  I assume that also explains all the MOD use in the original code.  Unmentioned in the problem text, the "answer" is unreasonably large and the assignment was for answer mode `1e9+7` so that MOD operation must be injected into my code.

Comment: sorry I'll edit . I did mention the constraints on N though. Also in your code you didnt initialise `j`.

Comment: @SarvagyaAgarwal This whole answer was in response to your request for psuedocode in the earlier comments.  So it is supposed to show the difficult ideas without the book keeping.  I assumed initializing `j` to zero or one was obvious (either works as long as you properly initialize `dp[j][]`)

Comment: I think i understand most of it now . regarding initialising the `dp[j][[]` table , `dp[0][0]=1;dp[1][0]=1;rest all 0 ` is  correct right ?! I'll see if this method works !

Comment: only `dp[j][]` is initialized (whichever initial `j` you choose).  Then one of `dp[j][]` is `1` and the rest `0`.  It is a design choice whether you mix in the base value by choosing which `db[j][]` will be 1 and then take the final answer from `dp[j][0]` or always initialize `dp[j][0]` to `1` and take the final answer based on the base value.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the initial input photo (string of characters `b` and `w`) ? Also a minor bug in both the `for loops` upper limit should be `<=1024`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97668/discussion-between-sarvagya-agarwal-and-jsf).

Comment: The initial photo `p` is your choice of either which position `dp[j][p]` is the only one set to 1 at the start, or which position is used for the final answer.  The other of those two things is `dp[j][0]`.  The upper limit in my code is correct `<1024`.  Using `<=1024` is seriously incorrect.